# How to make link to be opened by popup window or page?

Tags: html

[image]
This is my log-in and I need the popup window for the link "Change Password" instead of using self or blank. The picture shows the sample log-in and the link.

The code of the link:

```
<a href="Update Password.html" >Change Your password?</a>
```

Comment: I need the Small popup window that has text boxes like: Old password, New Password and Confirm Password

Comment: You don't. Every browser blocks them by default. Don't use it!

Comment: You may use something like `onclick="window.open(...`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function newPopup(url) {
        popupWindow = window.open(
            url,'popUpWindow','height=500,width=500,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
    }
    </script>
```

**Html**

```
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('Update Password.html');" >Change Your password?</a>
```

Comment: Can I add BACK and FORWARD buttons to IT. It doesn't have those buttons.

Comment: Ok, when the password is changed or not it display info. And this info is displays in a clean windows. so can i display the info on itself. If this is solved i don't need the BACK and FORWARD buttons. Thanks!

Comment: use ajax for display the result (password changed successfully , error try again) on same page. you do not need to create another page for display success messages..

Comment: yes, you got my Idea. I am a new for PHP world can you let me to find that?